# My code is repeating in a way that I don't want it to

Tags: java, loops, repeat

At the end of my code when the user chooses to repeat. When it does it outputs the whole loop with the original work instead of a new inputted word. For example if the user inputs the word Pizza. It will do the loop the way I that I want it to. When I choose to repeat it, the loop will use the word Pizza again instead of asking me for a different word.

```
do {
 if (answer == 1){
    System.out.println("Please enter another word:");
}
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
    firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
    word = word.substring(1, word.length());
    System.out.println(firstLetter + word);
    word += firstLetter;

}
 System.out.println("Would you like to Enter another word? If so, press 1. If not press 2.");
answer = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
}
    while(answer == 1);
    System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
}
}
```

The output for this code is:
pizza
izzap
zzapi
zapiz
apizz
Would you like to Enter another word? If so, press 1. If not press 2.
When I press 1 it will repeat it instantly without asking me for a new word. How can I get the desired result?

Comment: **Where** do you ask for another word **inside** of the loop? I mean, where do you have the Scanner get the next word? i.e., `word = input.nextLine();` Yours is a logic error, you just need to walk through your code thinking through the logic is all.

Comment: You should ask for input before you do anything else then depending on input go one way or the other. I think because you are asking for the input at the end of the while loop it messes with the logic.

Comment: This indentation is bad and it hurts my brain.

Answer (score 2):

```
System.out.println("Would you like to Enter another word? If so, press 1. If not press 2.");
answer = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine();
```

I think if you take out the last line it will work properly

Updated

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels tx, done

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this instead. You are missing the input for the word as well. You need both the word and the action from the user.

```
do {
    System.out.println("1 for new word, 2 for exit");
    answer = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("input word");
    String word = input.nextLine();

    if (answer == 1){   
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
            word = word.substring(1, word.length());
            System.out.println(firstLetter + word);
            word += firstLetter;
        }
    }  
} while(answer == 1);
System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
```

Comment: +1 This is the solution. The code requires two calls to `input.nextLine()`, one just to swallow the EOL, and the other to get the next word and place it into the `word` variable.